# making a dictionary of student from space separated single line user input where name will be key and list of exam numbers will be value

Tags: string, list, dictionary, input, key

Suppose I take one line space separated input as by using a string as : john 100 89 90
now from this string a dictionary is to be made as : d={'john':[100,89,90]}. Here, the numbers are to be collected in a list as integers. Basically from that input string line I want to make a student info dictionary where the name will be the key and the numbers will be exam numbers collected in a list as integers.

```
                 st=input()

                 value=st[1:]
                 c=list(map(int, value.split()))

                 print(c)

                 key=st[0]
                 d={}
                 d[key]=c
                 print(d)
```

I was writing this but mistakenly written key=st[0].. but this will only take the first character j as name and rest as values so I eventually got error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ohn'
So, how can I correct it and get the exact result that I mentioned above?? I also want to know alternative method for taking space separated input like john 100 89 90 other than strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct in a way , the only addition I would like to make is , have a preset delimiter string for student input info

```
student_dict = {}

loop_flag = True
loop_input = "Y"

delimit = "," #### You preset delimiter

while loop_flag:
   key = input("Input Student Name : ")
   if key in student_dict:
      print("Student already in Dictionary, continuing...."
      continue
   else:
      info_str = input("Input Student Information: ")
      info_list = info_str.split(delimit)
      student_dict[key] = info_list
   
   loop_input = input("Do you wish to add another student (Y/N)"
   
   if loop_input == "N":
       loop_flag = False
```

You can even use the space delimiter as well , but a more intuitive delimiter is suggested